# Dual of linear function with convex and non-convex constraints

Tags: derivatives, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I would like to compute the dual of the following problem by using the KKT conditions. However, due to form of the first constraint I am not able to obtain the dual. The problem is the following
\begin{eqnarray}
\min_{x,a} a  &\\
\text{s.t.}:   &\\
 & -x^H P^H_1 (cI + P_2 x x^H P^H_2 + P_3 x x^H P^H_3)^{-1} P_1 x - a \leq 0 \\
 & x^H D x \leq r \\
 & |x_n|^2 \leq s, n = 1,\dots,N \\
 & a \leq 0
\end{eqnarray}
where $ c, s, r > 0$, $ a \in \mathbb{R} $, $ x \in \mathbb{C}^{N} $, $ P_1, P_2, P_3 \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N} $

I have proved that the matrix $ (cI + P_2 x x^H P^H_2 + P_3 x x^H P^H_3)^{-1} $ is positive definite (PD). Then, it follows that the matrix $ - x^H P^H_1 (cI + P_2 x x^H P^H_2 + P_3 x x^H P^H_3)^{-1} P_1 x $ is negative definite. $ D $ is a diagonal positive semidefinite (PSD). Thus, the first constraint is non-convex, the second and third constraints are convex whereas the last one is linear. Any help will be welcomed.

** Update:

If it helps, I have the gradient of $ z = x^H P^H_1 (cI + P_2 x x^H P^H_2 + P_3 x x^H P^H_3)^{-1} $ w.r.t. $ x $
$$
\nabla_w z = x^H P^H_1 Y^{-1} P_1 - ( x^H P^H_2 Y^{-1} P_1 x x^H P^H_1 Y^{-1} P_2 + x^H P^H_3 Y^{-1} P_1 x x^H P^H_1 Y^{-1} P_3 )
$$
where $ Y = (cI + P_2 x x^H P^H_2 + P_3 x x^H P^H_3) $

Comment: You cannot say that a constraint is concave. What you mean is that the function in the inequality is concave, or that the feasible set is non-convex (i.e., your conclusion that the problem is convex is wrong, The set $x^TQx \geq y$ is non-convex when $Q$ is positive definite).

Comment: I mean to say that the first constraint represents a concave function. Yes, you are right, the set of the first constraint is not convex. Any idea how to proceed from here?

Comment: Optimization over a nonconvex highly nonlinear (due to the inverse) function, so no idea